# LDAP Object Class are able to mention in spring or not

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Currently developing an spring application and integrating with OUD through LDAP. I am new to LDAP. Is there is any provision to add the values in spring configuration

1. Group Object Class: companyPerson
2. User Object Class: groupOfUniqueNames

[image]

My understanding is these are object classes in ldap. Pl. Help me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'groupOfUniqueNames' is the LDAP marker objectclass for LDAP static groups, not for user entries, please see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519

'companyPerson' is not an LDAP standardized objectclass ,but seems to be a custom one.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard Thalmayr. Is there is any option to mention in spring-security like security_authentication, security_principal, security_credentials

Comment: What do you really want to achieve... only searching for specific entries?

Comment: Need to bind the dn. For that i have received the values of base dn, user search base, userdn, Group Object Class, User Object Class. Remaining values i mapped in spring application. These are the values are reamining. My understanding these variables are not the mapping variables. As you mention these are classes in LDAP. Is it right